# Migrate Mint->Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, mint, migration

Is there a fairly clean way to migrate from Mint (Petra, Cinnamon, 64bit) to Ubuntu (14.04 LTS, Gnome, 64bit) without losing most of my setup and application installs?

FWIW, /var and /home are on separate volumes from /boot and /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Backup the home folder
2. Wipe the partition and install Ubuntu from scratch.
3. Restore the home folder.

I wish there was an easy tool for migrating between distributions, but I don't think anything like that exists.

Comment: I am afraid this is all there is.  Makes switching distros a very big deal.

Answer (score 1):

try **AptOnCD**

install aptoncd in Mint  :- `sudo apt-get install aptoncd`

[image: Create a backup]

[image]
[image]

After taking backup **(.ISO)** from Mint then  install aptoncd on your ubuntu and Restore  **.ISO** file !!

Comment: Nope - this utility dies during the creation process for the image

Comment: I didn't know about this one. Anyway, one would have to be careful with the packages they copy and restore, as there may be some incompatibilities between distros.